How to show that $\left\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \left|\frac{z - 1}{z + 1}\right| < \frac{1}{2}\right\}$ is a disk
I have to prove that the equation
$$(z + 1)e^{-z} = 2(z - 1)$$
has only one solution in the open right half-plane. I know that if $z$ is a solution such that $\Re(z) > 0$ then $\left|\frac{z - 1}{z + 1}\right| < \frac{1}{2}$, so I represented this region with Wolfram Mathematica and checked that it's a disk of radius $\frac{4}{3}$ centered in $\frac{5}{3}$. I would like to show it formally in order to apply Rouché's theorem taking the simple closed curve as the boundary of this disk. Could you help me?

This answer is my favorite: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3432155/1101015

Thanks, but I don't like to see it by brute force. As @underflow has answered, I think I could see this problem in terms of the Möbius transformation given by $\frac{z - 1}{z + 1}$, but I don't know why I'm not able to see it right now…

If you know about Möbius transformations at all,  then you know that they take generalized circles to generalized circles.
Well, $f(z)=\frac {z-1}{z+1}$ is a Möbius transformation.
And $\mid z\mid=1/2$ is a circle.
So what does $f^{-1}$ do to this circle?
Well,  under $f^{-1}(z)=\frac{z+1}{1-z},$ the points $-1/2,1/2,1/2i$ are paired with $1/3,3,(i+2)/(2-i),$ respectively.
The latter $3$ points determine a circle. The solutions to $\mid f(z)\mid=1/2$ are thus the points on that circle.
Since $f^{-1}(0)=1,$ we see that $\mid f(z)\mid\le1/2$ is the disk whose boundary is that circle.
Now determine just what disk this is,  work with the equations: $$\mid z_0-1/3\mid=\mid z_0-3\mid=\mid z_0-(\frac {i+2}{2-i})\mid.$$

Well, your inequality is $2|z-1| < |z+1|$, if you write $z=x+iy$ and square the inequality you get
$$
4((x-1)^2 +y^2) < (x+1)^2 + y^2
$$
which becomes
$$
3x^2-10x+3y^2+3 < 0.
$$
Now is easy to see that is the disk you mentioned.
